# How to return the sum of functions dynamically in excel

Tags: excel, sum

I have the following table in my excel.

[image]

and I have the VBA function (fcComm) to calculate the some number with reference values as in =fcComm(A7,B7,D7,F7,"2:3"). 
For each row (for eg, Row 7) I will have values automatically generated in Scores table (from row 11 to 16).

But I have a scenario where I need to add more number of rows above row 10. and I would want my function to automatically give me the sum of results of function 
For example, 
If I have 3 players (40, 41, 42) in row 7, 8 and 9,  i want the following value in E13.

```
=SUM(fcComm(A7,B7,D7,F7,"2:3") + fcComm(A8,B8,D8,F8,"2:3") + fcComm(A9,B9,D9,F9,"2:3")).
```

Is there any function in excel to sum these values dynamically ?

Note: I am using =SUM(E7:OFFSET(E10,-1,0)) for some other function in the same sheet, but this particular table is bit unique and I am not sure how to use this.

Comment: You mean whenever you add new rows above row 10, E13 should update dynamically?

Comment: in that case you need a `Worksheet_Change` event

Comment: Maybe changing your function fcComm to take in a row or named range would help.  Let the function find the correct column.  fcComm(7, "2:3") for example.  Then you can create a new function that uses the rows as input and sums them all together: rng = range("7:9") sumId(rng)